# Rythm Blank lines for dynamic evaluation

Tags: rythm

```
@args String firstName, String lastName

Below is your name:
@if(firstName) {
FirstName: @firstName
}
@if(lastName){
LastName: @lastName
}
------------------------------
```

If firstName is passed as null, engine inserts a blank line. Is there any way to avoid it? "Compact" doesn't work here.

```
Below is your name:

LastName: Shah
------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately Rythm cannot handle blank lines properly. For structured document like xml, it's better to apply formatter to process the result

Comment: Any plan on fixing this?  I have both extra newlines and missing newlines, the latter even win using `@compact` and `@verbatim`.

Comment: @MBraedley there is no plan to fix this at the moment. Sorry about that